# Kentico v6 questions - Regarding 301 redirect, robots file & XML Sitemap

Tags: content-management-system, kentico, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I have Redirect non-www to www code ready but where to update the same in kentico v6?
How to update robots.txt file in kentico v6?
How can i add xml sitemap in kentico v6?

Comment: What does it mean: "I have Redirect non-www to www code"?

Comment: It means this 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

All of these items can be managed within the CMS.

To edit the redirect of a non-www domain name to a www domain, you can simply go to Site Manager>Settings>URLs and SEO>SEO - URLs>Process domain prefix.  Set this propety to "Always use domain with www prefix".

To have a dynamic robots.txt file, [follow this documentation](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?seo_robots_txt.htm).  It states it's for v7 but the steps are the same if v7 or v6.

To have a dynamic xml sitemap, [follow this documentation](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?google_site_map.htm).  It states it's for v7 but the steps are the same if v7 or v6.

Comment: Thanks brenden, will try this and get back to you